# Login and Registration crashes for second time

Tags: android

My app has a login and a registration activity. Whith registration everything is ok but with login it succeed ONLY when i put correct username and password. When either username or password are wrong the app crashes. That drives me crazy. The php files are based on mybringback.com site. Yesterday  Martin Konecny found a missing $login_ok = false; statement in login.php file and for a while app worked perfect. But today after a failure to login far from home my app denies either to login or register. I would appreciate any idea

```
Login.java

 package com.example.tranfer;

 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;

 import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
 import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
 import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Login extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private EditText user, pass;
private Button mSubmit, mRegister;

private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://...................";
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
public String v;
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.login);

//setup input fields
user = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtusername);
pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtpassword);

//setup buttons
mSubmit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.signin);
mRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.register);

//register listeners
mSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
mRegister.setOnClickListener(this);

}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
switch (v.getId()) {

case R.id.signin:
        new AttemptLogin().execute();
    break;
case R.id.register:
        Intent i = new Intent(this, RegistrationForm.class);
        startActivity(i);
    break;

default:
    break;
}
}

class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

 /**
 * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
 * */
boolean failure = false;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Προσπάθεια σύνδεσης...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
    pDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     // Check for success tag
    int success;
    String username = user.getText().toString();
    String password = pass.getText().toString();

    try {
        // Building Parameters

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

        Log.d("request!", "starting");
        // getting product details by making HTTP request
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
              LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

        // check your log for json response
        Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

        // json success tag
        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
        if (success == 1) {
            Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
            Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity1.class);
            finish();
            startActivity(i);
            return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
        }else{
            Log.d("Αποτυχία σύνδεσης!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
            return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;

}

protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
    pDialog.dismiss();
    if (file_url != null){
        Toast.makeText(Login.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}

}

}
```

Registration.Java

```
package com.example.tranfer;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class RegistrationForm extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private AutoCompleteTextView actv, actc;
public String v;
private EditText name, surname, mail, phone, user, pass, nomos, poli,    eidos,       exeidik;
private Button  mRegister;
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://...........................";
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration_form);

name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editname);
surname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editsurname);
mail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editemail);
phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editphone);
user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editusername);
pass =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editpassword);
nomos = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_cities);
poli = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_cities1);
eidos = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittransportsort);
exeidik = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittransportservices);


Here a omit some meaningless code....
/OnItemClickListener()

        mRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerbtn);
        mRegister.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

        new CreateUser().execute();

}

class CreateUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

 /**
 * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
 * */
boolean failure = false;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(RegistrationForm.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Creating User...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
    pDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     // Check for success tag
    int success;

    String onoma = name.getText().toString();
    String epitheto = surname.getText().toString();
    String email = mail.getText().toString();
    String tilefono = phone.getText().toString();
    String username = user.getText().toString();
    String password = pass.getText().toString();
    String edranomos = nomos.getText().toString();
    String edrapoli = poli.getText().toString();
    String eidosmetaforas = eidos.getText().toString();
    String exeidikypiresies = exeidik.getText().toString();


    try {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("onoma", onoma));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("epitheto", epitheto));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tilefono", tilefono));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("edranomos", edranomos));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("edrapoli", edrapoli));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("eidosmetaforas", eidosmetaforas));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("exeidikypiresies", exeidikypiresies));

        Log.d("request!", "starting");

        //Posting user data to script
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
               LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

        // full json response
        Log.d("προσπάθεια σύνδεσης", json.toString());

        // json success element
        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
        if (success == 1) {
            Log.d("Εγγραφήκατε!", json.toString());
            finish();
            return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
        }else{
            Log.d("Αποτυχία εγγραφής!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
            return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;

}
/**
 * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
 * **/
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
    pDialog.dismiss();
    if (file_url != null){
        Toast.makeText(RegistrationForm.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

 }
 }
 }
```

Login.php

```
<?php

//load and connect to MySQL database stuff
require("config.inc.php");

if (!empty($_POST)) {
//gets user's info based off of a username.
$query = " 
        SELECT 
            id, 
            username, 
            password
        FROM registration 
        WHERE 
            username = :username  ";

$query_params = array(
    ':username' => $_POST['username']
);

try {
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    // For testing, you could use a die and message. 
    //die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());

    //or just use this use this one to product JSON data:
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error1. Please Try Again!";
    die(json_encode($response));

}

//This will be the variable to determine whether or not the user's information is correct.
//we initialize it as false.
$validated_info = false;

//fetching all the rows from the query
$row = $stmt->fetch();
$login_ok = false;
if ($row) {
    //if we encrypted the password, we would unencrypt it here, but in our case we just
    //compare the two passwords
    if ($_POST['password'] === $row['password']) {
        $login_ok = true;
    }
}

// If the user logged in successfully, then we send them to the private members-only page 
// Otherwise, we display a login failed message and show the login form again 
if ($login_ok) {
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Συνδεθήκατε επιτυχώς!";
    die(json_encode($response));
} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Λανθασμένα στοιχεία!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}
} else {
?>
    <h1>Login</h1> 
    <form action="login.php" method="post"> 
        Username:<br /> 
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" /> 
        <br /><br /> 
        Password:<br /> 
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" value="" /> 
        <br /><br /> 
        <input type="submit" value="Login" /> 
    </form> 
    <a href="register.php">Register</a>
<?php
}

?>
```

Registration.php

```
<?php

/*
Our "config.inc.php" file connects to database every time we include or require
it within a php script.  Since we want this script to add a new user to our db,
we will be talking with our database, and therefore,
let's require the connection to happen:
*/
require("config.inc.php");

//if posted data is not empty
if (!empty($_POST)) {
//If the onoma or epitheto is empty when the user submits
//the form, the page will die.
//Using die isn't a very good practice, you may want to look into
//displaying an error message within the form instead.  
//We could also do front-end form validation from within our Android App,
//but it is good to have a have the back-end code do a double check.
if (empty($_POST['onoma']) || empty($_POST['epitheto']) || empty($_POST['email']) ||   empty($_POST['tilefono'])
|| empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password']) || empty($_POST['edranomos']) || empty($_POST['edrapoli'])
|| empty($_POST['eidosmetaforas']) || empty($_POST['exeidikypiresies'])) {


    // Create some data that will be the JSON response 
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Παρακαλώ συμπληρώστε όλα τα πεδία";

    //die will kill the page and not execute any code below, it will also
    //display the parameter... in this case the JSON data our Android
    //app will parse
    die(json_encode($response));
}

//if the page hasn't died, we will check with our database to see if there is
//already a user with the onoma specificed in the form.  ":user" is just
//a blank variable that we will change before we execute the query.  We
//do it this way to increase security, and defend against sql injections
$query  = " SELECT 1 FROM registration WHERE onoma = :onoma";
//now lets update what :user should be
$query_params = array(
    ':onoma' => $_POST['onoma']
);

//Now let's make run the query:
try {
    // These two statements run the query against your database table. 
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    // For testing, you could use a die and message. 
    //die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());

    //or just use this use this one to product JSON data:
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error1. Please Try Again!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}

//fetch is an array of returned data.  If any data is returned,
//we know that the onoma is already in use, so we murder our
//page
$row = $stmt->fetch();
if ($row) {
    // For testing, you could use a die and message. 
    //die("This onoma is already in use");

    //You could comment out the above die and use this one:
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Αυτό το username χρησιμοποιείται ήδη";
    die(json_encode($response));
}

//If we have made it here without dying, then we are in the clear to 
//create a new user.  Let's setup our new query to create a user.  
//Again, to protect against sql injects, user tokens such as :user and :pass
$query = "INSERT INTO registration ( onoma, epitheto,email,tilefono,username,password,edranomos,edrapoli,eidosmetaforas,exeidikypiresies ) 
VALUES ( :onoma, :epitheto, :email, :tilefono, :username, :password, :edranomos, :edrapoli, :eidosmetaforas, :exeidikypiresies ) ";

//Again, we need to update our tokens with the actual data:
$query_params = array(
    ':onoma' => $_POST['onoma'],
    ':epitheto' => $_POST['epitheto'],
    ':email' => $_POST['email'],
    ':tilefono' => $_POST['tilefono'],
    ':username' => $_POST['username'],
    ':password' => $_POST['password'],
    ':edranomos' => $_POST['edranomos'],
    ':edrapoli' => $_POST['edrapoli'],
    ':eidosmetaforas' => $_POST['eidosmetaforas'],
    ':exeidikypiresies' => $_POST['exeidikypiresies'],

);

//time to run our query, and create the user
try {
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    // For testing, you could use a die and message. 
    //die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());

    //or just use this use this one:
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error2. Please Try Again!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}

//If we have made it this far without dying, we have successfully added
//a new user to our database.  We could do a few things here, such as 
//redirect to the login page.  Instead we are going to echo out some
//json data that will be read by the Android application, which will login
//the user (or redirect to a different activity, I'm not sure yet..)
$response["success"] = 1;
$response["message"] = "Εγγραφήκατε!";
echo json_encode($response);

//for a php webservice you could do a simple redirect and die.
//header("Location: login.php"); 
//die("Redirecting to login.php");


} else {
?>
<h1>Register</h1> 
<form action="register1.php" method="post"> 
    onoma:<br /> 
    <input type="text" name="onoma" value="" /> 
    <br /><br /> 
    epitheto:<br /> 
    <input type="epitheto" name="epitheto" value="" /> 
    <br /><br /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Register New User" /> 
</form>
<?php
}

?>
```

And Log cat ( the red lines only)

```
06-01 20:56:29.599: E/JSON Parser(6207): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value Failed of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
06-01 20:56:29.599: W/dalvikvm(6207): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x410322a0)
06-01 20:56:29.619: E/AndroidRuntime(6207): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
06-01 20:56:29.619: E/AndroidRuntime(6207): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-01 20:56:29.619: E/AndroidRuntime(6207):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
06-01 20:56:29.619: E/AndroidRuntime(6207):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
06-01 20:56:29.619: E/AndroidRuntime(6207):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
06-01 20:56:29.619: E/AndroidRuntime(6207):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
06-01 20:56:29.619: E/AndroidRuntime(6207):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
06-01 20:56:29.619: E/AndroidRuntime(6207):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
06-01 20:56:29.619: E/AndroidRuntime(6207):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
06-01 20:56:29.619: E/AndroidRuntime(6207):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
06-01 20:56:29.619: E/AndroidRuntime(6207):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-01 20:56:29.619: E/AndroidRuntime(6207): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-01 20:56:29.619: E/AndroidRuntime(6207):     at com.example.tranfer.Login$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:112)
06-01 20:56:29.619: E/AndroidRuntime(6207):     at com.example.tranfer.Login$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:1)
06-01 20:56:29.619: E/AndroidRuntime(6207):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-01 20:56:29.619: E/AndroidRuntime(6207):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
06-01 20:56:29.619: E/AndroidRuntime(6207):     ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the exception message: it can't convert 'Failed' to a JSON object. You're probably expecting your login response to be a JSON object, but in case the login fails, your server is returning a simple 'Failed' message.

Either fix your server so that it returns a JSON, or your client so that it handles the 'Failed' value gracefully.

And try to remember that exception messages are very helpful.

Comment: can you be more specific? How to fix server: I use xampp. Do you mean repair php files?

Comment: just change your php site to send response via JSON not STRING !

Comment: isn't jsonParser.Java for this job;